# unsigned int arithmetic - beginner C

Tags: c, int, unsigned

At the risk of getting yelled at for posting a stupid question:

say I have the following code snippet:

```
unsigned int limit = 4294967296;
int math = 50000;

while(limit > 50000)
{
    limit = limit - math;
    printf("new limit is - \t%u\n", limit);
}
```

Would doing arithmetic between an unsigned int type and an int type have rammifications o n memory usage?

I know that an unsigned int has an order of magnitude more memory (2^31 for an int vs 2^32 for an unsigned int), but, since I'm using my unsigned int as a placeholder, i think I'm negating the danger of an overflow.

I would run this myself, but I don't have an accessible linux box right now.

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if there was a question here.

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact question, however you might find this site helpful.    http://ideone.com/

Comment: Expressions involving signed and unsigned types have all operands promoted to unsigned types. In your case, your loop has all chances of being executed infinitive number of types, because once you drop below 0, the result becomes a very large unsigned number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop forever since you will end up with wrap-around (i.e., `limit` will never be less than 0) ... is that your question?

Comment: What has anything to do with being less than zero? The OP's setup is fine, provided her `unsigned int` type is large enough for the initial number. (On my platform I have to switch to `unsigned long long int`.)

Comment: The loop does not check whether it's less than 0 but whether it's less than or equal to 50000. Thus it will eventually terminate.